# Trying to add min value from dict but error occurs. TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, dictionary, min

```
def shopaholic(shoppingList,costLimit,itemLimit):
    total=0
    item=0
    for i in range(itemLimit):
        for t in shoppingList.values():
            mintotal=min(t)
            total+=mintotal
    if total<=itemLimit:
        return No
    else:
        return Yes
```

Here is the code and whenever I run it I get an error message that says

`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.`

I've tried converting it to `int` but it didn't work
ShoppingList is the parameter for the dictionary, costLimit is the limit you can spend and itemLimit is the number of items you can buy.

Comment: Please show us how you call this method.

Comment: Please attach sample input and expected output.

Comment: what is `shoppingList`?

Answer (score 2):

instead of `mintotal=min(t)`, you need `min(shoppingList.values())`

Comment: not yet, since `min(shoppingList.values())` will return same value for `t` times, your `total` will be `min(...)*len(shoppingList())`. Looks like a Logical error